# Regex to match what's before or after a character in different situations

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some troubles writing a regex

What I want to achieve, I want to match the following string `6.62 X 25.250755 L` but only what is after the `X` character or there may be cases when I have to match the following string `25.250755 X 6.62`  in this case I need to match what's before the `X` character and the final case is when I have something like this: `25.250755 L X 6.62` or `25.250755L X 6.62` (with or without space, with or without the `L` character)

This is what I have so far, but is not enough and I don't know how to continue form here on

```
/[Xx]([\s\S]*)$/gm
```

Comment: Do you also need to extract those numbers?

Comment: @h-sifat yes, what I need is to get this number `25.250755` or any other number is there

Comment: what should be the match for these examples `25.250755 L X 6.62` or `25.250755L X 6.62` Is there any logic to it? What if the string is `25.250755L X 6.62L 123.45L` ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird the match for those string should be `25.250755` and `123.45`. These numbers represent the number of liters one have put in his car at a gas station and I am taking those numbers from a photo of the receipt the users sends to me

Comment: perhaps you can match the last capture of a repeating capture group `(?: ?(\d+(?:\.\d+)) ?[XL])+` https://regex101.com/r/I6FTsM/1 (The group value is highlighted in green)

Comment: Wow, it works, thank you so much @Thefourthbird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example data, you can repeat a group with a capture group to capture the value of the last iteration.

```
(?: ?\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)) ?[XL])+\b
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `?\b` Match an optional space and a word boundary
  - `(` Capture **group 1**

    - `\d+(?:\.\d+)` Match 1 or more digits with an optional decimal part
  - `)` Close group 1
  - `?[XL]` Match an optional space and either X or L
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat it 1 or more times
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vXyvck/1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1):

`([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+ ?L? X ([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+ ?L?` should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I am testing this and it seems to stop at the dot, it's how you intended? I would like to get the whole number